# Get length of a video using regex and ffmpeg

Tags: regex, ffmpeg

From the following `ffmpeg -i` output, how would I get the length (00:35)--

```
$ ffmpeg -i 1video.mp4

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/Users/david/Desktop/1video.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 1
    compatible_brands: isomavc1
     creation_time   : 2010-01-24 00:55:16
  Duration: 00:00:35.08, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 354 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x360 [PAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 597 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25k tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-01-24 00:55:16
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 109 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2010-01-24 00:55:17
At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: Why have you decided that you must use a regular expression? It looks like a simple string search (or on the shell, a combination of `grep` and `cut`) will do fine.

Comment: When using the [regex] tag, please always specify what language you intend to use. However, in this case, @Kerrek is correct - you don't need a regex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the shell

```
$ ff=$(ffmpeg -i video.mp4 2>&1)
$ d="${ff#*Duration: }"
$ echo "${d%%,*}"
```

Comment: say result is: 00:00:34.03 - how do we make this show in seconds... even if it's 01:34:03 - how can we make this show the total amount of seconds

Answer (score 29):

This way you get the duration in seconds. I think this is more convenient.

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams inputFile.mp3 | grep duration | cut -f2 -d=
```

ffprobe comes with ffmpeg so you should have it.

**EDIT:**
For a more dedicated version you could use for example

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format -show_streams inputFile.extension -print_format json
```

Instead of JSON you could also use e.g. CSV or XML. For more output options look here
http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html#Writers

Comment: You can add up all durations in the current directory with this bash one-liner: for f in *; do (ffprobe -loglevel error -show_streams $f | grep duration | head -1 | cut -f2 -d=); done | awk '{ s += $1 } END { print s / 60 " minutes" }'

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to do this in a bare shell pipeline, or read the result in a calling program?

```
/\s+Duration: ((\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)\.(\d+))/
```

… is a PCRE that will split the result up (replace the `\.` with `[;:.]` if ffmpeg might output the duration in frames rather than fractional seconds).  In a Unix pipeline:

```
| grep Duration: | cut -f2- -d: | cut -f1 -d, | tr -d ' '
```

There are of course a billion other ways to express this.

Answer (score 3):

Format (container) duration:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
30.024000
```

Adding the `-sexagesimal` option will use the `HOURS:MM:SS.MICROSECONDS` time unit format:

```
0:00:30.024000
```

Duration of the first video stream:

```
$ ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 input.mp4
30.000000
```

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FFprobeTips#Duration

Answer (score 2):

```
Duration: (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d(\.\d\d)?)
```

should work. Whatever your language's `$1` is will be the hours, `$2` will be the minutes, `$3` will be the seconds, and `$4` will be just the centiseconds if they are exist.

Answer (score 1):

for latest version :

```
$cmd = "avconv -i input.mp4 2>&1 | grep Duration | awk '{print $2}' | tr -d ,";
$output = exec($cmd);
echo "\n\n==OUTPUT===|".$output."|=====\n\n";
```

Now $output will hold your duration of video input.mp4

format will be: hh:mm:ss.ms

e.g
00:02:17.25