# amazon s3 video object Information

Tags: php, video, amazon-s3

In my current project, i am using Amazon S3 to store file. After uploading the video file into S3 server, i used getObjectInfo() method to get the information of that file. And it's return an array looks like this,

```
Array
(
[time] => 1358335793
[hash] => 8bc4fab9a5d3ae66963f8166f09d3a0f
[type] => application/octet-stream
[size] => 3144689
)
```

I just want to know what is the functionality of the key **time**? seems this is current timestamp. If so, is there any way to get the video duration directly from S3?

Regards

Comment: You cannot get the video duration directly from s3 unless you attach the duration tag to the s3 video file object while storing it.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon S3 server used to store files. Use FFMPEG to know the video duration. Here is a link to get length of video

[Get length of a video using regex and ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395343/get-length-of-a-video-using-regex-and-ffmpeg)