# Is there any way I can determine and limit the duration of the video being uploaded?

Tags: php, video, upload, extjs4.2

I am using Extjs 4.2 and php for uploading videos. But I want to limit the duration of the video with the available time the user is allowed to upload. My code only allows .avi and .mov .

Comment: You could validate movie length on the server side with `ffmpeg`. This means of course that you have to upload the movie first, and then validate it. I'm not aware, and would be surprised, if you could validate a movie's length on the client side... However, knowing your preferred upper limits, setting a reasonable file upload limit based on expected video size and quality, and then a second phase validation on the server side could be a reasonable strategy here?

Comment: I have tried to limit the video to only 2mb. Looks like it's near to impossible to limit the duration of the video when you upload it. Thanks fot answering!

Comment: yeah, it seems that the only robust solution is to define a sensible ballpark file limit (one that strikes a good balance btw likely video quality & duration). then as a 2nd phase run a process/cron/queue on uploads to check them on the server side with ffmpeg or something similar. I did dig into exploring a possible solution that might work on newer browsers, but it's very rudimentary and would not be very useful. I might post it in the interest of providing a starting point, or a feature for some browsers but... I wouldn't imagine it would be that useful. I'll fiddle around with it some more

Answer (score 4):

Okay, as I mentioned in the comments I was intrigued by this one so I decided to poke around and see what was possible. The short answer, not a lot. But in a *very* limited way it looks... sorta possible.

I want to preface this by saying that it's not really an answer per se, more of a proof-of-concept. It uses some HTML5 features like `<video>` and `FileReader` - I figured it might be possible to read the duration of a `<video>` tag so I did a fair bit of Googling on this.

Because they will obviously fail hard on older browsers... I only checked this on Chrome. I don't know if `FileReader` is implemented differently in Firefox. Neither can I speak for other video formats etc.

Anyway, I certainly would not rely on it for validation, but it could be a starting point for a 'convenience' validation feature for modern browsers?

I would still maintain that the only robust across-the-board validation solution here would be to:

- Allow upload of any video up to a reasonable ballpark size limit to your server.
- Create a queue/async process on the server that performs second-pass validation on the file itself. As I mentioned `ffmpeg` might be a good choice here?

  - Send success/fail email to user?

Incidentally, here's an SO answer that demonstrates [getting length of a video using ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395343/get-length-of-a-video-using-regex-and-ffmpeg)

Create a page `test.html` with an `input[type=file]` element:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>Duration</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="upload" type="file">
        <div id="duration">Please choose a video</div>
        <script src="path/to/duration.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The contents of `path/to/duration.js` script... excuse my JavaScript, it's far from perfect:

```
(function() {

  var upload   = document.getElementById('upload'),   // form input 
      duration = document.getElementById('duration'); // output for user

  // add a change event listener to the form input
  upload.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

    var file,
        reader;

    // check that a file has been selected
    if (this.files.length !== 1) {
      return;
    }

    duration.innerText = 'reading video...';
    file = this.files[0];

    // check the file's mime type, we want mp4 in this example
    if (file.type !== 'video/mp4') {
      duration.innerText = 'expected video/mp4, got ' + file.type;
      return false;
    }

    // create a FileReader object
    // and read the file as a data/url 
    // string so we can inline it later
    reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    // callback when the reader is complete
    reader.onload = function() {

      var video,
          timeout;

      duration.innerText = 'processing video...';

      // create a html <video> element
      // assign data/url as src
      video = document.createElement('video');
      video.src = this.result;

      // poll the video readyState until it's ready
      // this came from another SO answer (which I accidentally closed... sorry/thanks :s )
      // we should now have our video duration, so echo to the browser!
      timeout = setInterval(function(){
        if (video.readyState > 0) {
          duration.innerText = 'video is ' + video.duration + ' seconds';
          clearInterval(timeout);
        }
      }, 500);

    };

  }, false);

})();
```

Rough and ready!

- Here's a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/iTuVIXA/5/edit)
- Here's the [MDN FileReader API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

The HTML5 Rocks documentation was really helpful by the way.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Juste a note. Instead of using setInterval, you can listen for the "onCanPlayThrough" video's event:
`video.oncanplaythrough = function(){
   console.log('duration:', this.duration);
};`

Comment: Wow, I completely forgot about this question. Thanks for the update @LeonardDrs - I didn't hear about this event before. I'll look into that, and try to update the question as appropriate. I actually might need to use this proof of concept soon enough actually, so thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure its possible to find video length or validate video length in client side (Extjs).